# How to use regular expression to determine if one file concluding ISBN series?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, isbn

How  to use regular expression to determine if one file concluding ISBN series? on linux/unix.

And how about using Perl?

Thanks

Comment: Uh, what? Please give us an example of what you mean by "one file concluding ISBN series".

Comment: ISBN:  ***-***-***-*      (*:one digit)

Comment: Yeah, that's all fine and good, but what you do mean by "one file concluding ISBN series"? The last string in the file is an ISBN? The filename ends with an ISBN?

Comment: -1 because I have **absolutely no idea** what you're asking about, and you've ignored previous requests for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an easy regular expression for ISBNs, as hyphenation is variable (see the [hyphenation instructions](http://www.isbn.org/standards/home/isbn/international/hyphenation-instructions.asp)). What you could do is strip out all hyphens or spaces from your string, then check to see if it's 10 or 13 digits long (or 9 digits ending with either an `x` or an `X`). However, this doesn't handle verification of the ISBN, as the last digit (or letter, if it's an `[xX]`) is a checksum that verifies the ISBN is valid.

If you're using Perl, what you want to do is use the [`Business::ISBN`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Business-ISBN/) module, which saves you all of this trouble.